Concatenating pandas dataframe with multi index in different order
I have two data frames, which should be concatenated.
Both are multi index data frames with identical indexes, but in a different order.
So, the index of the first data frame (df) looks like:
MultiIndex([(11,  1, 1),
            (11,  1, 2),
            (11,  1, 3),
            ...
            (11, 24, 5),
            (11, 24, 6),
            (11, 24, 7)],
           names=['id_a', 'id_b', 'id_c'], length=168)

The second looks like:
MultiIndex([(11, 1,  1),
            (11, 2,  1),
            (11, 3,  1),
            (11, 3,  2),
            ...
            (11, 5, 23),
            (11, 6, 23),
            (11, 7, 23),
            (11, 7, 24)],
           names=['id_a', 'id_c', 'id_b'], length=168)

As you can see, indexes are in a different order.
Now by running pd.concat([df, df2]).index.names I get the following results:
FrozenList(['id_a', None, None])

How to reproduce
import pandas as pd

# create first data frame
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [['A1', 'A2', 'A3'], ['B1', 'B2', 'B3'], ['C1', 'C2', 'C3']],
    names=['a', 'b', 'c'])
cols = ['2010', '2020']
df = pd.DataFrame(1, idx, cols)

# Create second data frame with varying order
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [['A1', 'A2', 'A3'], ['C1', 'C2', 'C3'], ['B1', 'B2', 'B3']],
    names=['a', 'c', 'b'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(2, idx, cols)

result = pd.concat([df, df2])

Output
> df
          2010  2020
a  b  c             
A1 B1 C1     1     1
      C2     1     1
      C3     1     1
   B2 C1     1     1
      C2     1     1
      C3     1     1
   B3 C1     1     1
      C2     1     1
      C3     1     1
A2 B1 C1     1     1
      C2     1     1
      C3     1     1
   B2 C1     1     1
      C2     1     1
      C3     1     1
   B3 C1     1     1
      C2     1     1
      C3     1     1
A3 B1 C1     1     1
      C2     1     1
      C3     1     1
   B2 C1     1     1
      C2     1     1
      C3     1     1
   B3 C1     1     1
      C2     1     1
      C3     1     1
> df2
          2010  2020
a  c  b             
A1 C1 B1     2     2
      B2     2     2
      B3     2     2
   C2 B1     2     2
      B2     2     2
      B3     2     2
   C3 B1     2     2
      B2     2     2
      B3     2     2
A2 C1 B1     2     2
      B2     2     2
      B3     2     2
   C2 B1     2     2
      B2     2     2
      B3     2     2
   C3 B1     2     2
      B2     2     2
      B3     2     2
A3 C1 B1     2     2
      B2     2     2
      B3     2     2
   C2 B1     2     2
      B2     2     2
      B3     2     2
   C3 B1     2     2
      B2     2     2
      B3     2     2
> result
          2010  2020
a                   
A1 B1 C1     1     1
      C2     1     1
      C3     1     1
   B2 C1     1     1
      C2     1     1
      C3     1     1
   B3 C1     1     1
      C2     1     1
      C3     1     1
A2 B1 C1     1     1
      C2     1     1
      C3     1     1
   B2 C1     1     1
      C2     1     1
      C3     1     1
   B3 C1     1     1
      C2     1     1
      C3     1     1
A3 B1 C1     1     1
      C2     1     1
      C3     1     1
   B2 C1     1     1
      C2     1     1
      C3     1     1
   B3 C1     1     1
      C2     1     1
      C3     1     1
A1 C1 B1     2     2
      B2     2     2
      B3     2     2
   C2 B1     2     2
      B2     2     2
      B3     2     2
   C3 B1     2     2
      B2     2     2
      B3     2     2
A2 C1 B1     2     2
      B2     2     2
      B3     2     2
   C2 B1     2     2
      B2     2     2
      B3     2     2
   C3 B1     2     2
      B2     2     2
      B3     2     2
A3 C1 B1     2     2
      B2     2     2
      B3     2     2
   C2 B1     2     2
      B2     2     2
      B3     2     2
   C3 B1     2     2
      B2     2     2
      B3     2     2
> result.index.names
FrozenList(['a', None, None])

Indexes 'b' and 'c' are gone.

Can you provide a smaller [mre] of the two input DataFrames (max 10-20 rows) and the matching expected output?

Also, are you sure you want to concatenate on axis=0, not axis=1? In any case, I can't reproduce your issue.

@mozway Thanks for trying. I added an example.

FWIW, you can reduce the example size even further: [['A1'], ['B1', 'B2'], ['C1', 'C2']] and  [['A1'], ['C1', 'C2'], ['B1', 'B2']]. Only 8 rows.

@TobiasLorenz thanks, I had missed that the levels were not in the same order (thus the importance of MREs!). See below for a solution.

If your levels are in a different order, you first need to reorder them with reorder_levels:
result = pd.concat([df, df2.reorder_levels(df.index.names)])

If you have more than 2 DataFrames to concatenate:
dfs = [df, df2, df3, df4]

levels = dfs[0].index.names
result = pd.concat([d.reorder_levels(levels) for d in dfs])

Output:
          2010  2020
a  b  c             
A1 B1 C1     1     1
      C2     1     1
      C3     1     1
   B2 C1     1     1
      C2     1     1
      C3     1     1
...
A1 B1 C1     2     2
   B2 C1     2     2
   B3 C1     2     2
   B1 C2     2     2
...

